# Unwordle Solver Algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, wordle

**rules**

[UnWordle](https://unwordle.org/?daily=1) is a word guessing game in which it shows you a n*n color grid and a base word.  The goal of the player is to fill words into the grid such that it follows these rules:

- a green brick must contain a letter from the base word with correct positioning.
- a yellow brick must contain a letter from the base word but in an incorrect position
- a gray brick must NOT contain ANY letter from the base word
- a level beneath another level must use all the information from the level above it:

  - so: if a yellow or green letter is used on an higher level they must be used in a lower level
  - if a gray letter is used on an higher level they must NOT be used on the lower level
  - a yellow letter can not be used on the same index multiple times
  - if it is known that there's only M amount of letter k, you can not use more than that amount in you building

**example:**

[image: example starting position]
[image: example solution]

image on the left is the starting position.

image on the right is the winning position.

they follow all the rules mentioned above.

**problem**
I wrote code to solve the game, and it can solve 80% of the puzzle with no sweat, but it gets really slow as the question becomes more difficult. I am not sure if it was due to the algorithm or the flow of the program. The code was provided below.

[link to the dictionary file I use](https://replit.com/@ponggg/SimplisticAgreeableService#dictionary.txt)

---

**unwordle.py**

```
def help_() -> None:
    """message for help/-help flags."""

    s = """unwordle is a popular word game!
learn more about them here:https://unwordle.org/?daily=1
this program is a game solver.
first check out the unwordle game board.
then in command line type in `python unwordle.py `
if the first row is *green* *yellow* *gray* *gray* *gray*,
you would add `GYXXX` at the end of that command
you repeat this for the next two row.(all the hints)
and lastly typed in the answer word (letter only)
a sample output would look something like this:
`python unwordle.py YXXXX XYXYX XGYXG ralph\n`"""

    print(s)
    exit()
    return


def check_sys_arg(sys_argv: list) -> list:
    """
validating the input of the user.
<br>including checking if word is the right len
<br>and if contains disallowed characters.
  """

    
    ERROR_MSG_2 = ("include disallowed character in hint color:"+
"`G for green, Y for yellow, and X for gray`")
    ERROR_MSG_3 = "include disallowed character in answer word`"
    ERROR_MSG_4 = "inconsistent word length in input"

    ALLOWED_COLOR_S: set = set("GYX")
    ALLOWED_CHR_S: set = set("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")

    output = []

    wrd_ln = len(sys_argv[1])

    for x in range(1, len(sys_argv) - 1):
        x = sys_argv[x].upper()
        if set(x) - ALLOWED_COLOR_S:
            print("use `unwordle.py -help` to get help")
            raise Exception(ERROR_MSG_2)
        if len(x) != wrd_ln:
            print("use `unwordle.py -help` to get help")
            raise Exception(ERROR_MSG_4)
        output.append(x)

    x = sys_argv[-1].lower()
    if set(x) - ALLOWED_CHR_S:
        print("use `unwordle.py -help` to get help")
        raise Exception(ERROR_MSG_3)
    if len(x) != wrd_ln:
        print("use `unwordle.py -help` to get help")
        raise Exception(ERROR_MSG_4)
    output.append(x)

    return output


def import_dictionary(file: str = "dictionary.txt",
                      target_len_int: int = 5) -> list:
    """
reading and filtering words from txt files.
<br>file: the directory of which txt file is located
<br>target_len_int : target word length
  """
    output = []
    with open(file, "r+") as f:  #reading list of words
        temp = f.readlines()
        for word in temp:
            word = word.strip()
            if len(word) == target_len_int:
                output.append(word)
    return output


def color_word(answer_word: str, guess_word: str) -> str:
    """
take two words and color accordingly.
an example output would be "XXYYG"
  """
    color_l = ["X"] * len(guess_word)
    ans_wrd_l = list(answer_word)
    for counter, (chr_1, chr_2) in enumerate(zip(answer_word, guess_word)):
        if chr_1 == chr_2:
            color_l[counter] = "G"
            ans_wrd_l.remove(chr_1)
    for counter, chr_1 in enumerate(guess_word):
        if color_l[counter] == "G":
            continue
        if chr_1 in ans_wrd_l:
            color_l[counter] = "Y"
            ans_wrd_l.remove(chr_1)
    return "".join(color_l)


def find_candidate(wrd_l: list, final_ans: str, search: str) -> dict:
    """
loop through a word list and search for words that fit the criteria.
<br>the result to the function is a dict with:
<br>key being the word, val being a tuple of two set.:
<br>explain below:
<br>the first set contain sucess guesses(Y/G)
<br>the second set contain failed guesses:
<br>X or Y that is out of position
  """
    def multi_apperance(chr: str,
                        succes: set,
                        append_to: set,
                        break_: bool = True):
        for x in range(1, len(o) + 1):
            x = str(x) + chr
            if x not in success:
                append_to.add(x)
                if break_:
                    break

    output = {}
    for o in all_wrd_l:
        if color_word(final_ans, o) != search:
            continue

        fail = set()
        success = set()

        for counter, (chr, color) in enumerate(zip(o, search)):
            if color == "X":
                continue

            if chr in success:
                multi_apperance(chr, success, success)
            else:
                success.add(chr)

            if color == "Y":
                fail.add(counter * "X" + chr)

        for counter, (chr, color) in enumerate(zip(o, search)):
            if color != "X":
                continue
            if chr not in success:
                fail.add(chr)
            else:
                fail.add(counter * "X" + chr)
                multi_apperance(chr, success, fail, False)

        output[o] = (success, fail)
    return output


def main(cand_list: list, answer: str):
    """
collect a list of possible candidates and render result. always return 0.
<br>required args: 
<br>cand_list -> the candidate list. for reference only. 
<br>include a list of all possible candidate dict here.
<br>starting from clue 1 ...clue 3
<br> answer -> final answer
  """


  
    INSTRUCTION_MSG = """want a different answer?
enter 1 for a different answer or enter 0 to exit the program.
tip: you can enter any number and the word at that index will be changed
the left most word has a index of 1.
    """
    def askinput():
      print(INSTRUCTION_MSG)  
      while True:
        ask_input = input("your respond:")
        print()
        if not ask_input:
            ask_input = "1"
        ask_input = ask_input.strip()
        if set(ask_input) - set("1234567890"):
            print("invalid input, let's try again.")
        else:
            return ask_input
    def inner_main(depth: int,
                   cand_list: list,
                   answer: str,
                   display: list = [],
                   success_j: set = {},
                   fail_j: set = {}) -> 0:
        """The worker function for main."""

        i_cands = cand_list[depth]

        for cand in i_cands:
            success_i, fail_i = i_cands[cand]
            if display:
                if success_i - success_j:
                    continue
                if fail_i.intersection(fail_j):
                    continue
            display.insert(0, cand)

            if depth:
                _ = inner_main(depth - 1, cand_list, answer, display,
                               success_i, fail_i.union(fail_j))
            else:
                print("answer suggestion:")
                display.append(answer)
                print(display)

                _ = askinput()
              
                _ = int(_) - 1
                del display[-1]
            del display[0]
            if _:
                return _ - 1

        return 0

    inner_main(len(cand_list) - 1, cand_list, answer)
    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    print()  # print an extra line to avoid any confusion
    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        print("use `unwordle.py -help` to get help")
        print()
        exit()
    help_flags = ["h", "help", "-help", "-h", "--help", "--h"]
    if sys.argv[1].lower() in help_flags:
        help_()
        print()
    if len(sys.argv) == 2:
        print("use `unwordle.py -help` to get help")
        print()
        exit()
    user_input_l: list = check_sys_arg(sys.argv)

    WRD_LN = len(user_input_l[0])
    ANSWER = user_input_l.pop()
    GUESSES = len(user_input_l)

    all_wrd_l: list = import_dictionary(target_len_int=WRD_LN)

    cand = []
    for clues in user_input_l:
        temp: dict = find_candidate(all_wrd_l, ANSWER, clues)
        cand.append(temp)

    main(cand, ANSWER)
```

Answer (score 1):

### Efficiency

It would be better to create a new input file instead of
filtering out all the 5-letter words every time you run the code.

Also, the input file has many 5-letter combinations that, even
if they are considered "words" by some loose definition,
they are hardly common words:

```
abstr
accrd
accpt
ackgt
```

It would be better to use a smaller input file which only has
common words.  This may help your reported problem of your
code being too slow in some cases.

### Whitespace

[pylint](https://docs.pylint.org/index.html) identified a few style issues.
The code uses some inconsistent indentation, and some lines
have trailing spaces, which can be annoying and can certainly be removed.

The [black](https://pypi.org/project/black) program can be used
to automatically modify your code to fix these issues.

### Naming

You have a variable named `chr`, which is also the name of a
[built-in Python function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#chr).
It would be better to change the name of the variable to something like `char`.

Some short variable names are not very meaningful.  Consider changing them:

- `f` to `dictfile`
- `s` to `help_string`

You use the generic variable named `output` in a couple places.
It would be more meaningful to name it `words` in the `import_dictionary`
function, for example.

### Command line

[argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) is a standard alternative to
parsing the command line yourself.  It can generate a help message in a consistent way
as well as providing a built-in `-h` option.

### Documentation

It is great that you have the help documentation at the top of the file.

It would also be nice to mention that the code relies on the
`dictionary.txt` input file as well.

### Input checking

It is great that you check validity of data from the standard input.
Consider the [pyinputplus](https://pypi.org/project/PyInputPlus) module as well.

### Typo

The word `sucess` is misspelled in your docstring.  It should be `success`.

### Unused code

In the `help_` function, the `return` statement is unreachable because of the preceding `exit` statement.  `return` can be omitted.